# Is 'ON CONFLICT' support in PosgreSql Version 9.1.11?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have an error with code 'ON CONFLICT' when I use PostgreSQL with version 9.1.11

Comment: Are you sure you want to work with an outdated, unsupported and insecure version of PostgreSQL?

Comment: `On conflict` first appeared in 9.5. So you need to update, might as well make an supported version. That would be 11 or greater.